# How to install Cppcheck on a Linux server

Tags: linux, cppcheck

I want to use Cppcheck's XML report for SonarQube.

https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx/wiki/Code-checkers

But on Cppcheck's official site, I did not find any help with the installation on a Linux server.

Has somebody any working solution for this?

*Edit:
I like how the sonarqube tag disappeared, thank you @G. And again, for the constant "support". How convenient just to remove it, instead of helping, or letting someone to help who had these issues as well. Unrelated to the question, yes.*

*Then guess what: My boss wanted to demo this tool, but certainly told him now not to buy the commercial edition. Everything is unrelated with everything. Good marketing for 2017.*

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are no Cppcheck packages built for Linux. However, you may easily clone the Cppcheck repository from GitHub (https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck) and build it yourself. It has no extra dependencies and therefore is easy to build:

```
cd cppcheck-master
make
```

Also, I'm not sure about integrating Cppcheck with SonarQube, but there's a detailed article about SonarQube configuration, probably you may find something useful there: https://www.viva64.com/en/m/0037/

Comment: Thanks for the response, will try. 

Well, SonarQube theoretically can analyze the xml produced by Cppcheck.

Comment: Could not build it on the server. 

`lib/analyzerinfo.cpp:113: error: 'struct std::string' has no member named 'back'
make: *** [lib/analyzerinfo.o] Error 1`

Comment: Tried to build it on local, then move it remote, but when running the executable (./cppcheck) it misses libs there:
`./cppcheck: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by ./cppcheck)
./cppcheck: /lib64/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ./cppcheck)`

Comment: @MattSom, what Linux distribution you are using?

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago), Release: 6.8

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Well, if you're building cppcheck on a different platform, it is expected that some libs will be missing on your server. I'd suggest you build cppcheck right on the server. The error `lib/analyzerinfo.cpp:113: error: 'struct std::string' has no member named 'back' make: *** [lib/analyzerinfo.o] Error 1` means that cppcheck project uses features of C++11, and your version of GCC doesn't support it. You may check the version of GCC by issuing `gcc --version` and update it to the latest version.

Comment: Or, as an alternative solution, you may try to specify the `-std` flag in Makefile, something like this:

`CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11`

Comment: the Makefile had this part: 


`ifeq ($(CXX), g++)
    override CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x
else ifeq ($(CXX), clang++)
    override CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x
else ifeq ($(CXX), c++)
    ifeq ($(shell uname -s), Darwin)
        override CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x
    endif
endif`

Comment: changing the -std flag in the g++ branch, I get the error:
`cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
make: *** [lib/analyzerinfo.o] Error 1`